# Powershell Script to copy List items from one Column to another in a Sharepoint online Library

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, pnp-powershell

I have created a Powershell script to copy List items from one Sharepoint Library Column to another within the same Document Library. I am having trouble with getting the contents of list item.
This is the Powershell Script...

**-Add SharePoint PowerShell Snapin which adds SharePoint specific cmdlets**

`Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -EA SilentlyContinue`

**-Get the SPWeb object and save it to a variable**

`$web = Get-PnPWeb /sites/InterSignWorkgroup`

**-Variables that are used for list editing**

`$list = Get-PnPList "FWO History"`

**-Get all items in this list and save them to a variable**

`$items = Get-PnPListItem -List $list -Fields "Title".FieldValues`

**-Go through all items**

```
foreach($item in $items)
{
    $email = (Get-PnPListItem -List $list -Fields "Title").FieldValues
    Set-PnPListItem -List $list -Identity $item -Values @{"Customer_x0020_Email" = $email}        
}
```

***The return value that I am getting...*** "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]"

Is there a way to get the actual value of the field "Title" using Get-PnPListItem?

Answer (score 1):

Sample script for your reference, file Title is empty by default, so make sure Title has value.

```
#region Variables 
$Username = "user@tenant.onmicrosoft.com" 
$Password = "password" 
$siteURL = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/lee" 

#endregion Variables

#region Credentials 
[SecureString]$SecurePass = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force 
[System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]$PSCredentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($Username, $SecurePass) 
#endregion Credentials

Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteURL -Credentials $PSCredentials

$list = "MyDoc";
$items = (Get-PnPListItem -List $list -Fields "Title","GUID")

foreach($item in $items) {
$email = $item["Title"]
#Set-PnPListItem -List $list -Identity $item -Values @{"Customer_x0020_Email" = $email}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Corrected Script and now it is working...

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -EA SilentlyContinue

$web = Get-PnPWeb /sites/InterSignWorkgroup
$list = Get-PnPList "FWO History"
$items = Get-PnPListItem -List $list

foreach($item in $items) {    
    $lookup = $item.FieldValues["FWO_x0023_"]
    Set-PnPListItem -List $list -Identity $item -Values @{"Title" = $lookup}        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the field Title field you need this script:

```
$list = Get-PnPList -Identity "FWO History"
$listItems = Get-PnPListItem -List $list -Fields "Title"

foreach($item in $listItems)
{
    Set-PnPListItem -List $list -Identity $item['ID'] -Values @{"Customer_x0020_Email" = $item.FieldValues.Title}
}
```