# Copy a Sharepoint Listitem from one list to another using PnpPowershell

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, powershell, pnp-powershell, multiple-lines-of-text

I want to copy a list item from one list to the other using PnP PowerShell.

To copy a list item from one List:

```
Get-PnPListItem ???
```

And to paste the copied item to the other List:

```
Set-PnPListItem -List "MyList" -Identity "72" -Values @{"Omschrijving"="​​​Dit is een test"} -SystemUpdate
```

Column "Omschrijving" is a multiple-line column with rich text.
And will be the in format (bold, underlined etc..) of the text be copied too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to use `Get-PnPListItem` command to get the source list item & `Set-PnPListItem` to update the list item (or `Add-PnPListItem` to create new list item).

Check below links for more details & code snippets:

1. [Powershell Script to copy List items from one Column to another in a Sharepoint online Library](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/265359/powershell-script-to-copy-list-items-from-one-column-to-another-in-a-sharepoint)
2. [How To Copy SharePoint List Data From One List To Other Using PnP PowerShell](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-copy-sharepoint-list-data-from-one-list-to-other-using-pnp-powershell) - Adds new item in target list

Comment: I need in the Get-PnpListItem to get the text in the column "Omschrijving" of the first row. How can i do that? P

Comment: You need to pass the item `ID` to `Get-PnPListItem` command, like: `Get-PnPListItem -List listName -Id 1`. Where 1 is the item ID. You can pass the ID of item for which you want to get the column "Omschrijving". Check [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnplistitem) for more details.